# Ruby: How to execute only one if condition in a loop?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to only have one of the if conditions to print.

```
subnet = ['10.14.1.32/27', '10.17.8.2/29']
system = gets.chomp
subnet.each do |cidr|
  address_space = NetAddr::CIDR.create(cidr)
  if address_space.contains? system
    puts "found"
  else
    puts "not found"
  end
end
```

the output I get for something like 10.17.8.3 would be

```
not found
found
```

How would I only get one response? I tried using breaks but that doesn't work. Thanks All!

Comment: Your code outputs one OR the other for each element of `subnet`. Not sure what you expect

Comment: BTW, in order to help your readers understand your intent, collections should have plural names, so 'subnet' should be 'subnets'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick is to use the [`Enumerable#find`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) method:

```
subnet = ['10.14.1.32/27', '10.17.8.2/29'].collect do |cidr|
  NetAddr::CIDR.create(cidr)
end

system = gets.chomp

found = subnet.find do |cidr|
  cidr.contains?(system)
end

if (found)
  puts "found"
else
  puts "not found"
end
```

That will return either the CIDR object that matched or `nil` if nothing did.

Answer (score 0):

`subnet` is an array and your code using `each` loop. So if `subnet` is more than 1 elements it will return `subnet.count` result.
I do not know what exactly did you want. But if you want to break of loop in this case, you can using `return`